# Android studio doesn't run Flutter Application

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have just created a blank Flutter Application, but when I try to run the Application on Emulator it doesn't build and it throws an error. I don't know what I am missing. I have already fixed the Flutter to the stable version.

```
PS F:\Flutter Development> flutter doctor -v                                                                            [√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.720], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.9 at C:\src\Flutter
    • Framework revision f139b11009 (2 weeks ago), 2020-03-30 13:57:30 -0700
    • Engine revision af51afceb8
    • Dart version 2.7.2


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Android\Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = C:\Android\Sdk
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 45.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[√] VS Code (version 1.43.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\Bhavesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.9.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

• No issues found!
PS F:\Flutter Development>
```

Below is what I see in Android Studio:
I couldn't post the complete error here sorry I don't know how to thus I have added link for the same:

[Link for Seeing Complete Error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cAfLlSQSeHlMPkuABmdpT8M5ibcpCxc5/view?usp=sharing)

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\Flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```